# NSInvalidArgumentException iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax-error

My app is linked to fabric and in crashlytics (iOS 11.2.6 iPhone device) I've found this:

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>       *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
>       -[ApplicationEventsTableViewController actionSheetCreateOperationOfType:]

I'm stuck at solving this case, even after a proper reviewing the code I don't see anything that may cause a problem.

The part of the code is:

```
- (IBAction)addButtonAction:(id)sender {
    NSString *title = @"";
    BOOL isMale = [ApplicationUserSettings shared].authorizedUserIsMale;
    ApplicationActionSheet *actionSheet = [ApplicationActionSheet actionSheet];
    [actionSheet setButtonWithTitle:ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuCreateEvent") block:^{
        [self actionSheetCreateNewEventDidSelected];
    }];
    [actionSheet setButtonWithTitle:ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuCreateEvenOperation") block:^{
        [self displayPaymentAlertOrContinueWithBlock:^{
            [self actionSheetCreateOperationOfType:ApplicationOperationTypeIndexEven];
        }];
    }];
    [actionSheet setButtonWithTitle:ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuCreateSplitOperation") block:^{
        [self displayPaymentAlertOrContinueWithBlock:^{
            [self actionSheetCreateOperationOfType:ApplicationOperationTypeIndexSplit];
        }];
    }];
    title = isMale ? ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuIBoughtForSomeoneOperationM") :
                     ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuIBoughtForSomeoneOperationF");
    [actionSheet setButtonWithTitle:title block:^{
        [self displayPaymentAlertOrContinueWithBlock:^{
            [self actionSheetCreateOperationOfType:ApplicationOperationTypeIndexIBoughtForSomeone];
        }];
    }];
    [actionSheet setButtonWithTitle:ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuIGotMoneyOperationPlural") block:^{
        [self displayPaymentAlertOrContinueWithBlock:^{
            [self actionSheetCreateOperationOfType:ApplicationOperationTypeIndexTransferToMe];
        }];
    }];
    title = isMale ? ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuIGaveMoneyOperationM") :
                     ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuIGaveMoneyOperationF");
    [actionSheet setButtonWithTitle:title block:^{
        [self displayPaymentAlertOrContinueWithBlock:^{
            [self actionSheetCreateOperationOfType:ApplicationOperationTypeIndexTransferFromMe];
        }];
    }];
    [actionSheet setButtonWithTitle:ApplicationyLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuCreateDepositOperation") block:^{
        [self displayPaymentAlertOrContinueWithBlock:^{
            [self actionSheetCreateOperationOfType:ApplicationOperationTypeIndexDeposit];
        }];
    }];
    [actionSheet setCancelButtonWithTitle:ApplicationLocalizedString(@"eventsCreateMenuCancelButtonTitle") block:^{;}];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

And also might be useful, from *ApplcationActionSheet.m*:

```
+ (id)actionSheet {
    return ApplicationActionSheet actionSheet:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil cancelBlock:^{;} destructiveButtonTitle:nil distructiveBlock:^{;}];
}
```

and

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (self.cancelButtonIndex == buttonIndex) {
        CALL_BLOCK(((ApplicationActionSheetBlock)handlerBlocks_[@"cancelBlock"]));
    } else if (self.destructiveButtonIndex == buttonIndex) {
        CALL_BLOCK(((ApplicationActionSheetBlock)handlerBlocks_[@"destructiveBlock"]));
    } else {
        ApplicationActionSheetBlock block = handlerBlocks_[@(buttonIndex)];
        CALL_BLOCK(block);  << ACTUALLY, the log says it leads to crash >>
    }
}
```

The problem appeared twice, but for me important to get to the root of evil.
What are my options?

Comment: It may be helpful to also include your RepayActionSheetBlock code.

Comment: @LyndseyScott you mean '@interface' part from header? I've updated my post with last 2 parts

Comment: No, I was referring to what was initially labeled RepayActionSheetBlock and is now labeled ApplicationActionSheetBlock. It seems like there’s an issue with the ApplicationActionSheetBlock handlerBlocks_.

Comment: @LyndseyScott its NSMutableDictionary, I can send all the parts where its used but not sure it would help. Now im thinking that the problem is pointer `buttonIndex` as it might be somehow `nil`, isn't it? If so, I can simply fix it with `if (buttonIndex != 0) { <<lsat two strings>>} else{ <<catch that value and fix in further>>}` But im unsure

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are filling `handlerBlocks_` but it would seem there is a `nil` there somewhere. That's literally what this error is telling you, that you have a `nil` where you aren't expecting it (extremely common in Objective-C).

Comment: im not really into OBJ-C coding and C-relative languages as well, but in this file nil appears in '(id)actionSheet' as default value for 'actionSheet'. May be the best option is to add valueChecker to sort out 'nil's? If so, the question only where to

Comment: Or may be `buttonindex:` could be `nil`?

Comment: And backing up to your question, the part with `handlerBlocks_`: 
`@implementation RepayActionSheet {
    NSMutableDictionary *handlerBlocks_;
}`